# Duplicate data showing php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on Hotel Management System. I have a problem at my checkout page.

I want to show all the users who have reserved the room and are in the list of checkout. It's working when users reserve one room. If users reserve two or multiple rooms then the records repeat which I don't want.

Here is my query from where I am getting data.

```
SELECT 
  c.client_id, c.client_name, c.guests, c.address, c.no_of_rooms, 
  b.booking_id, rb.rb_id, rb.check_in_date, rb.check_out_date,  rb.room_no,
  t.total_price, t.extra_person, t.extra_amount, t.advance_amount,
  t.remaining_amount, t.payment_status, t.discount, t.payment_type, t.transaction_id 
FROM `clients` c, `booking` b, `rooms` r, `room_booking` rb, `transactions` t
WHERE r.room_status = 'Reserved' 
  AND 
  r.room_no = rb.room_no 
  AND 
  c.client_id = b.client_id 
  AND 
  b.booking_id = rb.booking_id 
  AND 
  b.booking_id = t.booking_id 
  AND 
  rb.check_out_date BETWEEN '$today' AND '$next_day'
```

Here I am showing the records who's checkout is **today($today)** and for the **next 30 days($nextday)**

Comment: Please always format your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your current query extract all the reserved room details from room booking table, If a user reserves multiple room obviously that entry would be displayed and you will get that user in two entries, in-order to only those users who are in checkout list you need to group the query by client id so that you will get all the users who are going to checkout.

**Update Query**

```
SELECT 
  c.client_id,     
  c.client_name,
  c.guests,
  c.address,
  c.no_of_rooms,
  b.booking_id,
  rb.rb_id,
  rb.check_in_date, 
  rb.check_out_date, rb.room_no,
  t.total_price,
  t.extra_person,
  t.extra_amount,
  t.advance_amount,
  t.remaining_amount,
  t.payment_status,t.discount,
  t.payment_type,
  t.transaction_id 
FROM 
 `clients` c, 
 `booking` b, 
 `rooms` r, 
 `room_booking` rb, 
 `transactions` t 
WHERE 
   r.room_status = 'Reserved' 
   and 
   r.room_no = rb.room_no 
   and 
   c.client_id = b.client_id 
   and 
   b.booking_id = rb.booking_id 
   and 
   b.booking_id = t.booking_id 
   and 
   rb.check_out_date BETWEEN '$today' AND '$next_day' 
GROUP BY 
   c.client_id
```

Comment: But in that case i got only one room of that user I already did that

Comment: You can get the total rooms count of that user by adding aggregate function in select clause such as "count(c.no_of_rooms)".

Comment: I am getting the no of rooms already but the problem is that i also have to got the room no's so that i can free that rooms accordingly

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, you were getting the rooms without the group by clause in your original query, If you want to see the rooms that user has booked then use group_concat. [see this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: I am getting the rooms with group by clause bro but the problem is that i only get one room but the user has reserved two rooms